# BLE android notifications read

Tags: android, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, characteristics

I'm experiencing an android application on Android Studio.

I'm actually able to enable and receive notifications or characteristics reads without problem.

Where I'm a bit stuck it's when I read characteristics (by button) if notifications are enable.
In my application the data from characteristics reading is right on a case and the notification's data on an other case. But when I read characteristics when notifications are enable, sometimes data exchange their places.

I tried to put a global variable which take a value on the ChangeValue Callback but it's not working all the time.

All of my new data is going on the class:

`private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {`

So here is my question, how to differentiate both data on this function?

Comment: Notifications arrive on the onCharacteristicChange callback and reads arrive on the onCharacteristicRead callback. How does the broadcast receiver fit into the picture? How are you sending the intents from your gatt callbacks?

Comment: Hey Emil, thank you about your answer.
Yes that's right. 
When a value is received, it goes on the BroadcastUpdate which send the intent into the sendBroadcast.

Comment: Then you should simply include some extra parameter in the intent that tells whether the data is a notification or a read response if that's what you want.

Comment: I had no idea that was possible, thank you so much about your help, that's very usefull !